# CollectionSizeQuota and DocumentQuota in Cosmos DB SDK v3

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am currently working on migrate Azure Cosmos DB sdk v2 to v3. In my previous codes, there are some usage like:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Document.Client

public string functionA(ResourceResponse<T> response)
{
  return string.Format(
      "collection size quota: {0}, document quota: {1}",
      response.CollectionSizeQuota,
      response.DocumentQuota);
}
```

I am trying to find the equivalent properties/methods of `CollectionSizeQuota` and `DocumentQuota` in `ItemResponse` from `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos`, but couldn't. Does anyone know how could I get these info? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are available as part of headers with container operation. You will need to enable [PopulateQuotaInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.containerrequestoptions.populatequotainfo?view=azure-dotnet) in the request and use the header values like below,

```
ContainerRequestOptions containerRequest = new ContainerRequestOptions();
containerRequest.PopulateQuotaInfo = true;
ContainerResponse containerResponse = await container.ReadContainerAsync(containerRequest);
Headers headers = containerResponse.Headers;
```